# How do I send an autoreply few minutes after the trigger in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms

I have a Google Apps Script code like this where I am sending an autoreply email upon submission of a Google Form. This will send an email immediately after the form submission but is there a way to send this autoreply 5 minutes after the form is submitted in Google Form?

```
function autoReply(e) {
  var values = e.values;

  ...

  var email = value3;
  var title = "EMAIL TITLE COMES HERE";
  var body = `
DEAR CUSTOMER,

EMAIL BODY COMES HERE
  `;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, title, "", {
    htmlBody: body
  });
```

Comment: Utilities.sleep()?  It might max the execution time per run, I need to double check. 
Or you can install trigger to run send email function.  Set the time as submitted time + 5 mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Utilities.sleep`, its max allowed value is 5 minutes/300000 milliseconds

Use this method before the lines which take care of the sending part of operation.

**Reference**

[Utilities.sleep](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know to accept. Just accepted.